# Allow HTML Content to Scale so Content isn't Bunched Up

Tags: html, css

I have HTML content that is both horizontally and vertically centered. It looks just how I want it to whenever my screen window is full size. However, if I shrink the window, the content gets bunched up together. What can I do so that the content will adjust with the shrinking of the window and not bunch together?

This the main CSS that I am using on the content that is horizontally and vertically centered...

```
#one {

    #image {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    }

    height: 5em;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#two {
    height: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id="my-div">

  <div id="header">
  </div>

<!-- Image and Table Name -->
    <section id="one">    
    <img src="image.png" id="image"><br><br>
    </section>

    <section id="two">
    <u id="text">Table Name:</u><br>
    <input type="text" value="Stage_Rebate_Index" id="tableNameInput" readonly><br><br>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Supplier ID">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form >
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_id">MR_ID</label>
      <select name="mr_id" id="mr_id_dialog" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="300">
          <?php foreach($user1->fetchAll() as $user2) { ?>
            <option>
                <?php echo $user2['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="supplier_id">Supplier ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="supp_id" id="supplier_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Form -->    
<form name="myForm" action="">

<!-- Dropdown List -->
    <select name="master_dropdown" id="mr_id">

    <!-- Javascript that sets 2nd dropdown as the value of the selected value in first dropdown -->    
    <script>
    document.querySelector('#mr_id').addEventListener('change', updateSelection, false);
    document.querySelector('#mr_id').addEventListener('change', updateSelection, false);

    function updateSelection(event) {
    // Get the value from this select
    var selectedValue = event.target.value;

    // find the select object that you want to set the value for
    var selectObjectToSet = document.querySelector('#mr_id_dialog');
    selectObjectToSet.value = selectedValue;

    // Call the function that was in the onChange listener
    updatetable(this.form);
    }
    </script>

    <option selected value="select">Choose a MR_ID</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user) { ?>
            <option data-name="<?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?>">
                <?php echo $user ['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Table -->
<p> 
    <div id="table_div">
        <table border="1" id="index_table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="display: none">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <td>MR ID</td>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($users_one->fetchAll() as $supp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id"><?php echo $supp['MR_ID'];?></td>
                <td class="supp_id"><?php echo $supp['Supp_ID'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div><br>

<button class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" id="insertButton">Add Supplier ID</button>
</section>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is your `HTML` code?

Comment: just use left:50%; and remove margin-right

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I posted my HTML code for you @MuhammadUsman

Comment: That didnt seem to work for me @Chiller

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Does this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yLmhxwpk/) solves your problem?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Yes it does! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Read about Responsive Design.
You need to use a viewport for that purpose.

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`